# How to use ToMany on Kotlin-Android (ObjectBox)

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

### I can't Build my code, make a mistake in the Build code process, I can work on java code

Gradle：3.2.1
ObjectBox: 2.2.0
Kotlin: 1.2.71

## error log:

> Could not find generated class "xxx_my_package_name_xxx.MainDataDB_",
>   please ensure that ObjectBox class generation runs properly before

## complete logs:

```
io.objectbox.gradle.transform.TransformException: Could not transform class "xxx_my_package_name_xxx.MainDataDB" (Could not find generated class "xxx_my_package_name_xxx.MainDataDB_", please ensure that ObjectBox class generation runs properly before)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.transformEntityAndBases(ClassTransformer.kt:148)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.transformEntities(ClassTransformer.kt:119)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.transformOrCopyClasses(ClassTransformer.kt:97)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ObjectBoxAndroidTransform.transform(ObjectBoxAndroidTransform.kt:178)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
---------------------------------------------------
Caused by: io.objectbox.gradle.transform.TransformException: Could not find generated class "xxx_my_package_name_xxx.MainDataDB_", please ensure that ObjectBox class generation runs properly before
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.findRelationNameInEntityInfo(ClassTransformer.kt:250)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.findRelationFields(ClassTransformer.kt:238)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.transformEntity(ClassTransformer.kt:184)
at io.objectbox.gradle.transform.ClassTransformer.transformEntityAndBases(ClassTransformer.kt:144)
... 55 more
```

## code:

```
@Entity 
data class MainDataDB(
    @Id var _id: Long = 0,
    val sort: String,               //类型
    val account_title: String,  //账号标题
    val account: String,        //账号
    val password: String,       //密码
    val url: String,            //网址
    @Transient var letters: String = "#",      //显示拼音的首字母
    @Backlink val pictures: ToMany<Picture>,    //关联的图片
    @Backlink val others: ToMany<Other>         // 关联的其他更多的内容
)


@Entity
data class Picture(
    @Id var _id: Long = 0,
    val base64: String,
    val data: ToOne<MainDataDB>
)


@Entity
data class Other(
    @Id var _id: Long = 0,
    val title: String,
    val content: String,
    val data: ToOne<MainDataDB>
)
```

Comment: reference data：[link](https://github.com/jonashao/next-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/junnanhao/next/data/model/Cluster.kt)
but it donesn't work

Comment: If no files are generated, did you maybe forget to apply the Kotlin kapt plugin in your app's `build.gradle`: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#optional-kotlin

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox  yes, is right.

Comment: So does it work now? If you are working based on this example: https://github.com/jonashao/next-kotlin/blob/master/app/build.gradle That is wrong. `apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'` should be last, after kotlin-kapt.
Exactly like here: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#optional-kotlin

Comment: At first I thought the problem was "How to use 'ToMany'", so I search "ObjectBox - filter Kotlin" on GitHub, I mainly refer to this file >[https://github.com/jonashao/next-kotlin/.../Cluster.kt](https://github.com/jonashao/next-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/junnanhao/next/data/model/Cluster.kt)  

 
My project was originally based on Java, the project already has the objectbox, so I just read doc: kotlin-support [https://docs.objectbox.io/kotlin-support](https://docs.objectbox.io/kotlin-support)  but there's no mention of using kapt, I ignored Java Api, haha :) @Uwe-ObjectBox

Comment: Thanks, I updated https://docs.objectbox.io/kotlin-support in that regard to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order in which your plugins are applied. Make sure that the ObjectBox plugin is last and that you have added kapt:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // if using Kotlin
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // if using Kotlin
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox' // apply last
```

Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started